# Optaplanner with Drools score director -- why not empty solution

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I've been looking at the [Cloud Balancing demo](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#quickStart) of OptaPlanner with Drools implementation.

There are 2 rules for this demo (there actually are 4, but 3 of those rules are of the same logic) --

```
rule "requiredCpuPowerTotal"
when
    $computer : CloudComputer($cpuPower : cpuPower)
    accumulate(
        CloudProcess(
            computer == $computer,
            $requiredCpuPower : requiredCpuPower);
        $requiredCpuPowerTotal : sum($requiredCpuPower);
        $requiredCpuPowerTotal > $cpuPower
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $cpuPower - $requiredCpuPowerTotal);
end
```

and

```
rule "computerCost"  // "Minimize the total maintenance cost."
when
    $computer : CloudComputer($cost : cost)
    exists CloudProcess(computer == $computer)
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $cost);
end
```

Going by these rules, the optimum solution is NOT to assign ANY of the processes to anyone of the computers. This will satisfy the first rule perfectly-- the `cpuPower` capacity is never exhausted, let alone gone over. 
And no computers will be used and thus no maintenance cost.

But the system finds a solution with these 2 rules only-- suboptimizes to assign the processes there are to the computers.

what am i missing, where?

Where is OptaPlanner/Drools told to allocate as many processes as possible?

new to Drools. excuse the naive question, if it is.

//--- UPDATE

the `@PlanningEntity()` instances to be initialized and put on `@PlanningSolution()` is the key I think. either explicitly in the code, or by a Construction Heuristic configuration as @yurloc suggested, or .. {don't know what else here if any}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#localSearchOverview:

> **Local Search needs to start from an initialized solution**, therefore it’s usually required to configure a [Construction Heuristic](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#constructionHeuristics) phase before it.

By default, Local Search expects that all entities are initialized and is not allowed to uninitialize them when making changes on the solution. The answer to your last question is that the **Construction Heuristic phase assigns a computer to each process** even though it actually worsens the score. The Local Search will improve the score in the next phase.

Thanks to this default behavior you don't have to write rules that penalize processes that haven't been assigned any computer.

For completeness, note that you can make planning variables [nullable](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#nullablePlanningVariable) but that is an advanced topic. Nullable planning variables are usually only useful for over-constrained planning.

Comment: I didn't configure any Construction Heuristic but still solving. see my update. thx for insightful ans.

Comment: OptaPlanner's aim is to work reasonably even with zero configuration. So if you don't have any `<constructionHeuristic>` and `<localSearch>` in your `solverConfig.xml`, OptaPlanner will still run CH and LS phases configured with default algorithms. If you're still working with the Cloud Balancing example, your `solverConfig.xml` will probably look similar to https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/7.33.0.Final/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml

Comment: so, is FIRST_FIT_DECREASING the default in all cases, how to see which heuristic is the default?

Comment: No. The default CH algorithm is `ALLOCATE_ENTITY_FROM_QUEUE`. It is the most generic form of CH and it's flexible. It means that it can behave like any specific algorithm, depending on whether your model supports entity difficulty comparison or value strength comparison. If your model supports none of that, it will behave like `FIRST_FIT`. If you implement entity difficulty comparison, it will behave like `FIRST_FIT_DECREASING`. More info in the documentation: https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#allocateEntityFromQueue.

Comment: It is better to specifically configure CH phase to use `FIRST_FIT_DECREASING` (or any other algorithm of your choice) than rely on the default `ALLOCATE_ENTITY_FROM_QUEUE` because this way, OptaPlanner will fail fast letting you know if your model doesn't support the algorithm that you're asking for.

Comment: so, if i make @PlanningEntity class implement entity difficulty comparison with no change elsewhere-- no constructionHeuristic configuration or anything, it'll be the FIRST_FIT_DECREASING heuristic. is that it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I don't know how to verify it. If you want to be 100% sure that solver runs `FIRST_FIT_DECREASING` algorithm in the CH phase, add it to the configuration.